# SEO with for a Quarto blog, in particular make website "findable" with specific keyword

Tags: seo, meta-keywords

I am maintaining a website with [Quarto](https://quarto.org/).

We are a group belonging to the "For Future" movement. One typical keyword, that people use in order to look for us is H4F ("health for future"). I don't really want to include "H4F" visibly on the website, because I don't like the abbreviation too much, but it would be really cool to find a way to enable search engines to link our site to searches like "h4f dresden".

Does anyone have any advice on how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know. You can't have it both ways, you dont like but you still want to use it.

Google uses keywords based on their usage on you website, to ensure that they are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the first thing to determine the best how to, for this site and editorial style, put yourself in the position of somebody doing a search for the abbreviation, (think in terms they don't know what it means ... you did that for us here, thank you.

Basically, if a NOOB like myself searches for H4F and lands on your page, If I don't see H4F somewhere I'm confused, as a NOOB I don't know what H4F means. So I click the back button. In this case, NOOB friendly is SEO friendly.

I generally do the same for abbreviations: LOL "lots of laughs". Beyond that **you can create a page that explains what the term** "lots of laughs"; And, for SEO do a link within the text to that page. Thanks to your post I know H4F is ("health for future"), but I am clueless as to what "health for future," actually represents or means; I guess I'm a NOOB. By **linking to the definition on a FAQ page Google draws out the relationship**.

The pages linked to represent a greater resource of knowledge that Google uses to determine the ranking and quality of the page ... page theme if you will.

### There used to be a time when the term did not need to exist on the page

at that time people could link bomb terms ... IE Microsoft – “More evil than satan himself,” 1999 Google-Bomb. https://blogs.cornell.edu/info2040/2017/10/21/microsoft-more-evil-than-satan-himself-1999-google-bomb/

[image]

But today the term needs to appear on the page or have strong indications such as linking to other pages that contain the term in order for Google to apply the term. For the More evil than satan himself bomb to work today, Microsoft only needs to put the words, satan is evil, onto the page, maybe even an image with an alt tag.

So you could **link bomb your site with H4F from what Google refers to as "hidden gems"** (those would include comments on other sites). Recent announcements by Google is they will be promoting these pages as part of E-E-A-T, ("expertise", experience, authority, trustworthiness). But H4F needs to appear somewhere on the page. FYI LinkedIn seems to benefit as having hidden gems so far.

Relevant Meta tags for self-link bombing.

```
 <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
 <meta property="og:title" content="" />
 <meta property="og:description" content="" />
 <meta property="og:url" content="" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="" />
```

But @Rohit is correct: Google looks at the keywords on the website to determine relevance.

However, Google has expanded allowing keywords to not exist for long tail (a search phase instead of one or two keywords) searches and tells you in the SERP the keyword is missing. I would suggest having the keyword at least one click away, at least in the FAQ page linked to on the page footer. But since the space on the footer is small does it not make sense to use the abbreviation in the footer?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful.